# Tomcat startup issue

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I am using tomcat6(distribution) integrated with Netbeans 6.5. It was working with no issues and now suddenly stopped working. Now if i try to start Tomcat from netbeans in console it prints server starts up in some millisecond and all other things abut even after that , netbeans keep on showing the status bar of "starting tomcat" and finally shows "Tomcat startup failed". can any one help me to resolve this? Below is the console output while starting the netbeans

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   E:\Tomcat distri\apache-tomcat-6.0.20
Using CATALINA_HOME:   E:\Tomcat distri\apache-tomcat-6.0.20
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: E:\Tomcat distri\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\temp
Using JRE_HOME:        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11
Sep 22, 2009 10:52:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin;.;C:\SYSROOT\Sun\Java\bin;C:\SYSROOT\system32;C:\SYSROOT;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin;E:\Oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_4\bin;E:\Oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_4\jre\1.4.2\bin\client;E:\Oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_4\jre\1.4.2\bin;C:\SYSROOT\system32;C:\SYSROOT;C:\SYSROOT\SYSTEM;C:\SYSROOT\system32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\CA\eTrustITM\;C:\Program Files\CA\SharedComponents\ScanEngine\;C:\Program Files\CA\SharedComponents\CAUpdate\;C:\Program Files\CA\SharedComponents\ThirdParty\;C:\Program Files\CA\SharedComponents\SubscriptionLicense\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;E:\Thomas
Sep 22, 2009 10:52:28 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 22, 2009 10:52:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 999 ms
Sep 22, 2009 10:52:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 22, 2009 10:52:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.20
Sep 22, 2009 10:52:29 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 22, 2009 10:52:29 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Sep 22, 2009 10:52:29 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/47  config=null
Sep 22, 2009 10:52:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 974 ms
```

Tomcat log :

```
    Sep 22, 2009 10:36:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 22, 2009 10:36:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 22, 2009 10:52:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Sep 22, 2009 10:52:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
```

Comment: try to start tomcat after restarting your system. There will be more logs. Please post that too

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with net beans, but it seems that it launches an "empty" tomcat, and then does hot deploys of the applications.

Comment: it deploys the application properly..and even tomcat is getting started..but netbeans still shows the error..

Comment: Can you please post some exceptions from the logs (if you have any)